# Nestjs Service level caching

Tags: nestjs

Looking at Netsjs documentation I can see that the general approach is controller level caching utilizing CacheInterceptor,

What I am looking to achieve is Service/DB level caching - use case is mainly for Static DB data that is required by other services, Is there a way to extend the supplied Cache Module to be used from within services ?

Answer (score 2):

I was also looking for a way to do this.

For now I made it work based on some research by injecting the cacheManager instance in the service, and using it directly.

```
import { CACHE_MANAGER, Inject, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  constructor(
    @Inject(CACHE_MANAGER) protected readonly cacheManager
  ) {}

  public async myMethod() {
    const cachedData = await this.cacheManager.get(cacheKey);
    if (cachedData) return cachedData;

    const data = ''; // Do normal stuff here

    this.cacheManager.set(cacheKey, data);

    return data;
  }
}
```

But I'm still looking for a way to create a caching decorator that would contain the cache logic, and would use the function arguments as cache key

Comment: how do you register the cache in the first place? using your solution gives me the error `can't resolve dependencies of the Service (?). Please make sure that the argument CACHE_MANAGER at index [0] is available`

Comment: Make sure to import `CacheModule` to the module of your service, or just register `CacheModule` globally like so: `CacheModule.register({ isGlobal: true })`

Answer (score 2):

This is how I do it (some hook):

```js
import {CACHE_MANAGER, CacheModule, Inject, Module} from '@nestjs/common';
import {Cache} from 'cache-manager';

let cache: Cache;

@Module({
    imports: [CacheModule.register({ttl: 60 * 60})]
})
export class CacheableModule {
    constructor(@Inject(CACHE_MANAGER) private cacheManager: Cache) {
        cache = cacheManager;
    }
}

export const Cacheable = (target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) => {
    const originalMethod = descriptor.value;
    descriptor.value = async function (...args: any[]) {
        const cacheKey = originalMethod.name + "_" + args.join('_')
        const cachedData = await cache.get(cacheKey);
        if (cachedData) {
            originalMethod.apply(this, args).then((data: any) => {
                cache.set(cacheKey, data);
            })
            return cachedData;
        }

        const result = await originalMethod.apply(this, args);
        cache.set(cacheKey, result);
        return result;
    };
};
```

2. and use it

```js
@Cacheable
async getProducts(projectName: string): Promise<{ [id: string]: Product }> {}
```

Comment: I like this solution. I attempting to implement...

```
.../node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js:553
                    var decorated = decorator(target, propertyKey, descriptor);
                                    ^
    TypeError: decorator is not a function
```

(Unfortunately cant use a code block in comments)
thanks

Comment: How would this solution look or work if we don't depend on a file scoped global variable cache? Would prefer to have DI-injected cache, manager instead, as this is not clean at all.

Answer (score 2):

Going to use this in my future projects

```
import { CACHE_KEY_METADATA, CACHE_MANAGER, CACHE_TTL_METADATA, Inject } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Cache } from 'cache-manager';
import { PROPERTY_DEPS_METADATA } from '@nestjs/common/constants';

export const Cacheable = (target: object, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor): void => {
  const injections: { key: string; type: string }[] =
    Reflect.getMetadata(PROPERTY_DEPS_METADATA, target.constructor) || [];
  if (!injections.some((injection) => injection.type === CACHE_MANAGER)) {
    const injector = Inject(CACHE_MANAGER);
    injector(target, CACHE_MANAGER);
  }
  const originalMethod = descriptor.value;
  descriptor.value = async function (...args: unknown[]): Promise<unknown> {
    const cacheKeyPrefix =
      Reflect.getMetadata(CACHE_KEY_METADATA, descriptor.value) ||
      Reflect.getMetadata(CACHE_KEY_METADATA, originalMethod) ||
      `${target.constructor.name}:${originalMethod.name}`;
    const ttl =
      Reflect.getMetadata(CACHE_TTL_METADATA, descriptor.value) ||
      Reflect.getMetadata(CACHE_TTL_METADATA, originalMethod) ||
      1000;
    const cacheKey = [cacheKeyPrefix, args.map((arg) => JSON.stringify(arg)).join('_')].filter((v) => v).join('_');
    const cacheManager = (this as { [CACHE_MANAGER]: Cache })[CACHE_MANAGER];
    const cachedData = await cacheManager.get(cacheKey);
    if (cachedData) {
      return cachedData;
    }
    const result = await originalMethod.apply(this, args);
    await cacheManager.set(cacheKey, result, ttl);

    return result;
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to use Nestjs's CacheModule in non-controller classes, but you can simply use `utils-decorators`'s [`@memoizeAsync`](https://vlio20.github.io/utils-decorators/#memoizeAsync) decorator for this purpose. It uses a `Map` as cache but supports any caches (like *Redis* for distributed caching).

```js
import { memoizeAsync } from 'utils-decorators'
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm'
import { Item } from './item.entity'

class ItemsService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(Item)
    private readonly repo: Repository<Item>
  ) {}

  // a one minute ttl
  @memoizeAsync(1000 * 60)
  findItems(): Promise<Item[]> {
    return this.repo.find()
  }
}
```

PS: Take a look on other decorators of this useful package. ;)

Answer (score -3):

You can use one of the cache stores listed here: https://github.com/BryanDonovan/node-cache-manager#store-engines

Then you simply register that store in the cache module (https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/caching#different-stores):

```
import * as redisStore from 'cache-manager-redis-store';
import { CacheModule, Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';

@Module({
  imports: [
    CacheModule.register({
      store: redisStore,
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 6379,
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
})
export class ApplicationModule {}
```

Comment: I understand it, but the general cache approach is to use interceptors - which aim to cache controller results based on route, and not on service level