# How to reset cache value based on parameter in nestJS or Typescript?

Tags: typescript, caching, nestjs

I have a nestJS application with @Get() methods with some parameters and body. I want to store all responses of particular method with all different parameters in cache. For Example

```
  @UseInterceptors(CacheInterceptor)
  // @CacheKey('Check')
  async check(@Query('search') search: string): Promise<string> {
   //Some code
    return search;
  }
```

Currently this function has one search parameter and I want to store every response with different parameter in cache. So, if the same parameter comes, response will come from cache only. 
By using @UseInterceptors(CacheInterceptor), currently cache key is stored like whole route URL with parameter and all and I can store all responses in cache but I am not able to reset cache based on parameter. 
If I use @cacheKey('key'), for every parameter, it is giving same response from cache.
So, how can I use cache manager to store all the responses with different parameter in single cache and how can I reset particular one response of given parameter instead of whole cache value of that function? 
I have found this [https://snippets.cacher.io/snippet/b02445aad5f4cf6f637a] but no idea how to use this.

Comment: Why do you need to manually reset the cache?

Usually you would just set a timeout for the cache to expire after a given time, which can be done when importing the CacheModule into your Module

Comment: For example, my cache value got change before timeout so i need to reset that particular cache.

Comment: Maybe something like this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59047801/nestjs-service-level-caching

If you inject the cache manager instance, instead of using the interceptor, you will have more control over it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69156422/get-multiple-redis-cache-keys-based-on-pattern-with-nestjs