# Get Multiple Redis Cache Keys based on Pattern with NestJS

Tags: typescript, redis, nestjs

Currently I have created a NestJS application with a Redis Cache.  I want to be able to get multiple keys from my Redis Cache by using a pattern where I can get all the keys that include some string.

Currently I am using *cache-manager* and *cache-manager-redis-store* as my client to be able to connect and access my Redis Cache. I have gone through the documentation to try and use the .mget() function but I am not able to figure out if I can somehow pass a string and get all the keys that include that string.

Im thinking I might have to go with a different Redis client but just wanted to see if anyone had any other ideas.

Comment: https://redis.io/commands/scan

Answer (score 4):

There is property named `store` in `cache-manager` from which you can get all keys by calling `keys()` method.

This is example redisService

```
import { Injectable, Inject, CACHE_MANAGER } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Cache } from 'cache-manager';

@Injectable()
export class RedisCacheService {
    constructor(@Inject(CACHE_MANAGER) private readonly cache: Cache) {}

    async getKeys(key: string): Promise<any> {
        return await this.cache.store.keys(key);
    }

    async getValue(key: string): Promise<string> {
        return await this.cache.get(key);
    }

    async save(key: string, value: any, ttl: number): Promise<any> {
        return await this.cache.set(key, value, {
            ttl: ttl,
        });
    }

    async delete(key: string): Promise<void> {
        return await this.cache.del(key);
    }

    async getMultipleKeydata(key: string): Promise<any> {
        const redisKeys = await this.getKeys(key);
        const data: { [key: string]: any } = {};
        for (const key of redisKeys) {
            data[key] = await this.getValue(key);
        }
        return allData;
    }
}
```

Then you can use this service to get multiple keys or can get values of multiple keys

`await this.redisService.getKeys('*' + email + '*');`

Also you can get values of multiple keys

`await this.redisService.getMultipleKeydata('*' + email + '*');`

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can accomplish this

1. keep a SET of keys that you want to retrieve and do SMEMBERS.  However, you will have to manually maintain the SET and add and remove.
2. [Redisearch](https://oss.redis.com/redisearch/) allows you to create secondary indices around data for full text search etc

Comment: Thank you! im thinking of keeping all the keys in the cache as well as a value and then I can grab that first and do my logic to figure out all the keys I will need to update.  So im assuming that this means that there is nothing that the client gives us here that we can use to get all the keys I need?